# NULL values getting stored into hive external table while importing from SQL Server using sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop

SQL Server table `MSR` (with 1000 records) columns (ID int, LastName varchar, FirstName varchar, age int)

```
1 cosmos msr 15
2 cosmos msr 15
3 cosmos msr 15
4 cosmos msr 15
5 cosmos msr 15
6 cosmos msr 15
7 cosmos msr 15
8 cosmos msr 15
9 cosmos msr 15
10 cosmos msr 15
.
.
.
```

Created a hive external table :

```
hive> create external table msrhivedb.hivetab(id int,lastname string,firstname string,age int)
> row format delimited
> fields terminated by ' '
> stored as textfile;
```

Now tried to import the SQL Server table to hive using this sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.25.3.196;username=hadoop1;password=London123;databaseName=AdventureWorks2012' --table MSR --hive-import --hive-table msrhivedb.hivetab --target-dir /hdfsfile -m 1
```

But null values are getting loaded into the hive external table.

Kindly suggest a solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Null values"*: on all rows? on some rows? on all columns? on some columns?

Comment: Did you look into the HDFS files created by Sqoop to check **what kind of delimiters it uses by default**? And to begin with, did you read the Sqoop User Guide at chapter *Importing Data Into Hive* and especially the default column delimiter being `\01`, not "space"?